# How to align an image and a paragraph in the same line in css?

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a design in which a paragraph and an image are aligned in the same line as shown below:

[image]

At this moment, I am able to get this is in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6n8pgb5y/4/embedded/result/). I am using Bootstrap 3. I tried using `display: inline-block, display: block and display: inline` but unfortunately still I am unable to put the the paragraph and an image in the same line as shown above in the design.

The HTML code for the paragraph portion is:

```
<div id="line2" class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="cofounder-ceo-image">
    <img src="assets/img/Uploads/jack.jpg"> </div>
     <p>Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at floating elements. This may help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float

Comment: You are using the grid system in the html you included, so why don't you put the image into a column?

Answer (score 1):

You are already using a grid, so put the image into a column. This means that the grid system will manage it all for you, instead of trying to work with floats and manage it yourself.

***Floats which are not ideal in this situation*** because they take the element out of the flow which can introduce other issues, like extending out of the container, messing up the layout, etc.

**Example of adding the image and text into a new row with 2 columns:**

```
  <div id="line2" class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="cofounder-ceo-image">
          <img src="https://s26.postimg.org/6lwl4wpxl/jack.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <p>Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever
          you say Whatever you say </p>
        <p class="ceo">ABC DEF - Co-founder and CEO</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Additional CSS required (to make the image responsive)**:

```
.row img {
  width: auto;
  max-width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

This will make it fit the width of the container up to 100% of its size. i.e. it won't stretch to more than its actual width. 
This is the only change that you need for your CSS - you certainly don't need to start adding spans, etc.

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/cvaxvzbf/

**Notes:**

1. The image is in a 4/12 column (i.e a third of the row), and the text is in 8/12 - you can change this to suit.
2. On small displays (< 768px), the image and text will appear on separate lines - otherwise the image could be too small. If you want to change this, you can use `col-xs-?` e.g. `col-xs-6` on both columns to make them each 1/2 the width
3. The CSS above will make the image fit into the column width if the column is smaller than the image. It won't make the image stretch to fit the column if it is wider (i.e. it will never display the image bigger than its actual size) - if you want to do that, change the width to 100%.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work out. Can you make changes in the fiddle ?

Comment: @user5447339, I've updated my example to use bootstrap 3 classes and explain the changes to your code, I also updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cvaxvzbf/

Comment: @user5447339 Did this work for you or do you need more help with it?

Answer (score 0):

You must use float and direction: rtl;

```
#line2 .cofounder-ceo-image{float: left;}
#line3{direction: rtl;}/*this is for right align like arabic*/
#line3 .cofounder-ceo-image{float: right;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float: left` to make the image to "float" near the paragraph.

Something like that

```css
img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="line2" class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="cofounder-ceo-image">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/ee/bd/cc/eebdcc1600cae9e1d7ac3ef5e33b8778--series-on-netflix-drama-series.jpg"> </div>
  <p>Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you say Whatever you
    say Whatever you say </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply float the image, for example:

```
    <img style="float:left;" src="assets/img/Uploads/jack.jpg">
```